# parsing the values from the json file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, rspec, specifications

This is a sample.json file as follows

```
{
"name": "Jack (\"Bee\") Nimble",
"format": {
    "shape": "rect",
    "width": 1920,
    "height": 1080,
    "interlace": false,
    "framerate": 24
 }
}
```

In the spec file the sample.json file has been opened.

```
describe Samplespec do
  before :all do
  @jsonfile = File.open('sample.json').read
  @file_json = Samplespec.new(@jsonfile)
 end
```

I've written this in the sample.rb file

```
require 'json'
def initialize(val)
 @parsed_val = JSON.parse(val)
end
```

This doesn't seem to work. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Doesn't seem to work? What error do you get, what happens?

Comment: the sample.json file is being displayed as it is{
"name": "Jack (\"Bee\") Nimble",
"format": {
    "shape": "rect",
    "width": 1920,
    "height": 1080,
    "interlace": false,
    "framerate": 24
 }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably seeing the same output from JSON.parse as Ruby's `Hash#to_s` is roughly the same format as JSON.  This code (your code) works for me:

```
json = '{
"name": "Jack (\"Bee\") Nimble",
"format": {
    "shape": "rect",
    "width": 1920,
    "height": 1080,
    "interlace": false,
    "framerate": 24
 }
}'

require 'json'
def parse(val)
 @parsed_val = JSON.parse(val)
end

json = parse(json)

puts json
puts json['name']
```

So, the first `puts` will appear to output JSON again (it's just Hash#to_s), but the second `puts` will correctly as expected output just the `name` key.